# Solving the functional equation $f\left(x\right)+f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)=1+x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\backslash\left\{0,1\right\}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $$f\left(x\right)+f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)=1+x$$ Find $f\left(x\right)$.

I tried plugging for $x$ as $\frac{x-1}{x}$, but that didn't lead me anywhere. Could someone suggest a more helpful substitution?

Comment: Have a look at the related posts at the right side!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you need to substitute it twice. It is due to the fact that the transformation $\phi(x) := \frac{x-1}{x} = 1-\frac{1}{x}$ is an element of order 3 with respect to composition, meaning $\phi \circ \phi \circ \phi = \mathrm{id}$. In consequence, you are facing three unknowns, namely :
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
   f_1 &:= f(\phi(x))             &= f(1-\frac{1}{x}) \\
   f_2 &:= f(\phi(\phi(x)))       &= f(\frac{1}{1-x}) \\
   f_3 &:= f(\phi(\phi(\phi(x)))) &= f(x)
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then, the functional equation you were provided permits to generate a system of three equations for these unknowns :
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
   f(x) + f(\phi(x)) = 1-x \\
   f(\phi(x)) + f(\phi(\phi(x))) = 1-\phi(x) = \frac{1}{x} \\
   f(\phi(\phi(x)) + f(\phi(\phi(\phi(x)))) = 1-\phi(\phi(x)) = -\frac{x}{1-x}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
It can be recasted matricially in the following way :
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} f_1 \\ f_2 \\ f_3 \end{pmatrix} 
= 
\begin{pmatrix} 1-x \\ \frac{1}{x} \\ -\frac{x}{1-x} \end{pmatrix}
$$
I let you invert this matrix and solve it for $f_3 = f(x)$.

Of course, you could have done the same substitutions "manually", i.e. without introducing all the new notations; however, here you have a procedure to tackle similar problems when the transformation $\phi$ belongs to a finite group.

Comment: Thank you, but I still haven't learned matrices yet (we'll be taught about this next year). Just wanted an elementary approach to the question. Nevertheless, I'll make sure to return to this problem once I learn matrices!

Comment: In that case, you may solve the system 
$$
\begin{cases}
   f_2 + f_3 = 1-x \\
   f_1 + f_2 = 1/x \\
   f_1 + f_3 = -x/(1-x)
\end{cases}
$$
with elementary methods, i.e. with the mean of substitutions and/or linear combinations of the different rows. Actually, add the first equation to the last one, then substract the middle one and you will end up with $2f_3 = \ldots$